# Securing a symmetric encryption key in memory

Tags: c#, security, cryptography, encryption-symmetric, dpapi

I have an application where I am retrieving the symmetric encryption key present in the disk and using it to encrypt data. The encryption key is retrieved from the disk when the program starts and is stored as an array of bytes in a private class variable. Right after the key is retrieved from the disk on the start of the program, `ProtectedMemory.Protect()` is used on the key to protect it. The key is unprotected by `ProtectedMemory.Unprotect()` every time it needs to be used and is again protected after use.

The parts which has got me pondering on the effectiveness of this scheme is during the instances where the key is retrieved from the disk and every time the key needs to be used as an easily exploitable vulnerability is created during 2 key moments in the program's execution cycle: when the program has just finished loading the key from the disk and has not called the `Protect()` method and when the key is unprotected for use during encryption.

```
class ApplicationClass {
   private byte[] encKey;

   public ApplicationClass() {
     // Fetches the encryption key first
     encKey = StorageInt.FetchKey(); // Fetches and returns the encrypted key from the disk

     // A gaping vulnerability here as the key is just loaded in memory and is not protected
     ProtectedMemory.Protect(encKey, MemoryProtectionScope.SameProcess);

     // Other initialization instructions follows
   }

   private byte[] ApplySymmEnc(byte[] plaintext) {
     Aes aes = Aes.Create();
     byte[] iv = new byte[128];
     RNGCryptoServiceProvider randomBytesGenerator = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
     randomBytesGenerator.GetNonZeroBytes(iv);
     randomBytesGenerator.Dispose();
     ProtectedMemory.Unprotect(encKey, MemoryProtectionScope.SameProcess);

     // Another gaping vulnerability here!

     ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(encKey, iv);
     ProtectedMemory.Protect(encKey, MemoryProtectionScope.SameProcess); // Protect the key right after it is used for encryption

     // Instructions for encryption follows
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: As for the reason on being unconcerned about the key's security while on the disk, the key exists in a reasonably secure obfuscated form in the disk which is deciphered by the `StorageInt.FetchKey()` function while retrieving.

Comment: What is the weakest chain in your link? Is the key protected on disk, for instance?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The key remains reliably safe while on the disk. The weakest chains, I believe, must be the two scenarios specified in the post.

Comment: .net has special clr type for secure key store in memory: SecureString (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netcore-3.1). I would load key from secure storage like x509 cert store in windows - it looks safe.

Answer (score 3):

Protecting against **all** attacks is impossible. The closest you could get is probably using a [Trusted Platform Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) (tpm) chip so the key never leaves the chip. Second best may be to use a [trusted execution environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_execution_environment) if such is offered by your processor. But neither is impervious to all kinds of attacks.

If dedicated hardware support is not available it is probably not feasible to try to protect your program from an administrator. If the attacker can read the memory of your program, why could he not just read the key from disk?

Encrypting the key in ram is useful to protect against things like cold-boot attacks, and such attacks would probably be difficult to time right to get the key at a vulnerable moment.

There are also some answers in the question [best practices for keys in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263350/cryptography-best-practices-for-keys-in-memory) that might be useful.

Comment: The key, while one the disk, is reasonably secure as opposed to it being on the memory.

Comment: Could you motivate that or provide a source? Memory is in general protected against other processes. I reason that if the attacker has permission to access the process memory then he should be able to do whatever the process is doing, including reading the disk. Is my reasoning faulty? Or are you worried about inadvertent memory leaks like heartbleed?

Comment: The reason I mentioned the key is secure while on the disk is because it is securely obfuscated and is deciphered when loaded to memory. My major concern in this matter is that the key must be secure/undecipherable from all acts of intrusions like, but not limited to, memory dumping and buffer overrun (like Heartbleed, the vulnerability mentioned in your last comment).

Comment: "Securely obfuscated" is not a thing. If the attacker has access to the key on disk and the program files he can reverse whatever obfuscation there is. .Net clears all allocated memory, and has checks to prevent buffer overruns, so the risk of leaking data is rather small. If the attacker has physical or administrator access then the short window the key is decrypted is probably the least of your worries. If the attacker achieves remote code execution he can undo whatever protection you apply.

Comment: One option is to store the password as a cyphered number. see https://www.nuget.org/packages/Walter.Cypher/ password scanners will skip it a they look for anything but numbers

Answer (score 0):

Keeping symmetric encryption keys protected during those times (after fetching from disk but before calling ProtectedMemory.Protect) would need OS level support, which doesn't exist in Windows (and other .net core platforms).

Directly from the .net team on a similar topic dealing with credentials:  "The purpose of SecureString is to avoid having secrets stored in the process memory as plain text. ... However, even on Windows, SecureString doesn't exist as an OS concept ... It **just makes the window getting the plain text shorter** ... The general approach of dealing with credentials is to avoid them and instead rely on other means to authenticate, such as certificates or Windows authentication" (https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md)

Answer (score -1):

You have mentioned

> "when the program has just finished loading the key from the disk and
> has not called the `Protect()`"

If I rephrase the above sentence `StorageInt.FetchKey()` is fetching you an unprotected key and you want to protect it at this point.

You could create an extension method for `StorageInt.FetchKey(bool IsProtectKey = true)` this method can call `ProtectedMemory.Protect()`. You can use only the extension method to fetch key.

```
public int StorageInt.FetchKey(bool IsProtectKey = true)
{
    encKey = StorageInt.FetchKey();
    CodeEncryptedKey = EncryptAndStoreProtectedKey(); 
    //Above function should encrypt your "encKey" to AES256 or to any secure encryption algorithm, store it in cache and return encrypted key
    
    ProtectedMemory.Protect(encKey, MemoryProtectionScope.SameProcess);            
}
        
Public string UseKey(string CodeEncryptedKey)
{
    encKey = GetProtectedKeyFromCache(CodeEncryptedKey)
    ProtectedMemory.Unprotect(encKey, MemoryProtectionScope.SameProcess);
    Task.Run(() => ProtectKeyAfter5Seconds(encKey));
    return encKey;
}
        
Void ProtectKeyAfter5Seconds(encKey)
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000); //I'm telling here to encrypt after 5 seconds, you can have your logic to encrypt after one-time use or any particular logic
    ProtectedMemory.Protect(encKey, MemoryProtectionScope.SameProcess);
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: How do you presume to protect the key in the extension method?

Comment: The Extension method should call both fetchkey() and protect(). So the extension method return value would be always be protected keys.

Comment: Adding an extra layer of the extension method you mentioned does not resolve the problem at hand which comprises of protecting the key right after it is fetched from the disk and deciphered.

Comment: Updated my solution and have added code for using the extension method. Check if this can help you

Comment: Still does not resolve the issue revolving around protecting the newly fetched key in memory RIGHT AFTER it is fetched. Besides, choosing to encrypt the key throws in another problem in the fray: how do you plan to secure the IV and the key used to encrypt the key fetched from the disk?

Comment: If you are using the keys frequently and don't want to call disc at all instances, then at any point you don't have plain form keys available easily. Another way could be, fetch the key only when needed, and soon after the key is fetched after 5 seconds protect it. Dont use Unprotect at all, use only fetchkey.

Comment: Please refer to the question as I am afraid that you have misunderstood the whole problem at hand. The key is always only fetched once and your solutions do not resolve the issue in any way.

Comment: oh, I get your issue now. Protecting key may not be possible  all the time